# RandomAccessFile using by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, randomaccessfile

I have many threads all reading (just READING) from the same file.
In each thread I instantiate a `RandomAccessFile` and then use Seek and try to get read a byte chunk. The problem is that I am getting

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
```

Is there anyway using Java to access the same file concurrently?

Or is it better to create a layer that make the file access?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you're working with? Something that comes to mind although it may not prevent the object from locking the file is declaring the `RandomAccessFile` with a mode of reading only like so: `RandomAccessFile() file = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");`

Comment: Err, don't try to create overlapping locks, of course. But why are you creating locks at all? They won't protect the threads from each other.

Comment: Moreover, you are only reading the file, the locks seem redundant.

Comment: And why have you wrapped the exception in a `RuntimeException`?

Comment: Guys sorry! The exception was throwed by Level DB http://leveldb.org/. I was using the leveldb::DB incorrectly in multithread enviroment. I think it is better to close this thread.